# How ```valuePropName``` Works?

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, antd

I have a form with checkBox component. But when I submit the form whithout `valuePropName` . The checkBox value is `undefined`

```
<Form.Item name="remember" valuePropName="checked">
          <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>
```

I get the value when valuePropName is setted.

I'd like to know the why and how valuePropName whorks.

Comment: How can we know? What is `Form`? Did you define it or a library? If so, which one? Did you check the documentation for it? There's a lot of important information missing here.

Comment: I'm using ant design. Here's the api of Form.Item

https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.Item

valuePropName has a description, but I didn't understand

Comment: `valuePropName` is the name of the prop of the child component that will contain the value. In most cases, components such as `Input` or `Select` use `value` as the prop for holding the value. However, certain components such as `Checkbox` or `Switch` use `checked`. Since your child component is a `Checkbox`, you need to manually specify the `valuePropName` as `checked` because the default is `value` (this is why `Input`/`Select` components don't need this manual specification).

Comment: woww. Thanks @scratchnpurr. I understand right now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think valuePropName specifies the name of the property that must be used as the value.
For example, in the Checkbox component, valuePropName can be used to specify the name of the property that should be used as the value when the checkbox is checked. By default, this property is value, but you can specify a different property name by setting the valuePropName prop.